# Is Meta SE a good place to post bugs and feature request to traducir.win?

Tags: support, localization, traducir

In the end of the 2018 for at least two sites: [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) were decided to use [traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11285) site to make or update translations used on the sites interface by the volunteers.

As far as I know traducir project is not maintainted by SO team officially, so I'm asking:

Is Meta SE a good place to post bugs and feature request to traducir.win?

It would be easier for me (and I think for many other guys contributing to the translations on the localized sites) to post such posts on MSE rather than on any external for Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Consider emailing [the developer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4) at the email address they provide and they may be able to create issues for you or implement the changes for you.

Comment: There is also a [chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win) which you can ask to unfreeze. (e.g. in Tavern)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The project is community run. First idea was implemented on SO en español, once we found out that every change on source code on SO was breaking our translations.

The main developer is [g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4). I'm one of the contributors.

If you post an issue on github, at least me an Gerv receive the notification and can take care of it.

Posting here, would be rather difficult at least for me to read it (i'm not a usual user of meta.se).

Also we have a chat room (as pointed out on the comment) [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win) that can be unfreezed if you need something (we are always watching it).

You can ask on [The terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) about unfreezing it if you need it, I'm usually around there, too.

Anyway, Gerv will have the last word about it, since he is the main developer.

Answer (score 10):

The project appears to be community run. Since it is not officially run by the Stack Exchange team I'd recommend filing an issue on the [GitHub](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues) repository used by that site. This site is primarily about discussing the software powering the Stack Exchange Network and this app doesn't fall within the scope defined in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).